# Rails 3 + Paperclip + Amazon S3 + Download All Images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, amazon-s3, paperclip

### Background

- I have been running a rails 3.X.X app for 2+ years on Heroku.
- User-uploaded images are stored in an Amazon S3 bucket via Paperclip.

### What I Need

- I want to download all images that have been uploaded (around 5000 images total) to a local disk.
- I'd like to reduce the cost required to perform this query.

### Problem

- My knowledge of how Paperclip stores files on S3 has escaped me (the app was written almost 3 years ago).
- Viewing the bucket's content within the S3 console lists what appears to be meta-data text-files containing a link to the image.
- I can't seem to find any image files within the bucket itself (via the S3 web console).

### Solutions?

- I've tried various applications like [Cyberduck](http://cyberduck.io/) and [Buckets](http://bucketsapp.net/) but they all time out trying to request the bucket's content.
- It seems odd that my production bucket only contains meta-data text files describing an image's location; why can't I see the images in the console itself?
- Is there some easy script I can run to grab all images?

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide some additional information about your `has_attached_file` method declared in your model?

You could do something like this assuming you have `has_attached_file :photo`:

```
Model.find_each do |record|
  puts record.photo.url
end
```

`puts` will obviously just show you the URL. You'll want to script iterating over the list and fetching them with curl or wget.